# Display users logged in data

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display the users data from the table, so once the user has logged in to the website, text shows on the page saying "Welcome (firstname) (lastname)."

The columns for firstname is "Firstname" and lastname is "Lastname".
I have tried many different methods, but all of them seem to return errors and I cannot get it to work. If anyone can help, that would be great.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Landing page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* ESTABLISH FIRST YOUR CONNECTION TO YOUR DATABASE */
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "user_login"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?")){
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$checklog = $stmt->num_rows;

if($checklog > 0){
  /* HERE IS YOUR CODE WITH SUCCESSFUL LOGIN */  
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["logged_in"] = "YES";
  echo "<h1>You are now logged in</h1>";
  echo "<p><a href='secure1.php'>Link to protected file</a></p>";
  echo "<p><a href='secure2.php'>Link to protected file #2</a></p>";

}
else {
  /* HERE IS YOUR CODE WITH UNSUCCESSFUL LOGIN */
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["logged_in"] = "NO";
  echo "<h1>You are NOT logged in </h1>";
  echo "<p><a href='secure1.php'>Link to protected file</a></p>";
  echo "<p><a href='secure2.php'>Link to protected file #2</a></p>";
}

$stmt->close();
}

?>
<p><a href="public.html">Public Page</a></p>
<p><a href="logout.html">Logout</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Where is your code you have tried for echoing `"Welcome (firstname) (lastname)."`? and what error you are getting?

Comment: You need to fetch Firstname and Lastname in your query and then print them by using result variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

And store your Result in the `$result`

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)  
$Firstname = $result["Firstname"];
```

As you might have only one matching row, I would recommend you have to have your condition like `$checklog==1`

So, You shall have something like this

```
$checklog = $stmt->num_rows;
if($checklog == 1)  // Allows only for one match
{
session_start();
$_SESSION["logged_in"] = "YES";
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  // Fetch the row into $result
$Firstname = $result["Firstname"]; // This is your First Name
$Lastname = $result["Lastname"]; // This is your Last Name
}
```

You can have the `First Name` and `Last Name` in your session like this

```
$_SESSION["FirstName"] = $result["Firstname"];
$_SESSION["LastName"] = $result["Lastname"];
```

**Update :**

Here's the cool and entirely updated version that is hand made just for you :)

*It took my cool 10 minutes to construct it :)*

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_login",'root','');
$name = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = ? AND Password  = ?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name,$pass));
$count = $q->rowCount();
if ($count==1) 
{
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
while($row = $q->fetch())
{
echo $row['FirstName']; //Just to show you output
session_start();
$_SESSION["FirstName"]  = $row['FirstName'];
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: It is displaying an error: syntax error, unexpected '$Firstname' (T_VARIABLE).  Sorry, I am still learning PHP

Comment: Sorry, Its my fault i missed the `;` in the line `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ` I have updated it , can you try with this ?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help; however a new error stating: "Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given" on line 27:"$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  // Fetch the row into $result" Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer, You can check it now.. Sorry for late reply :)

Comment: I am not sure whether you have `FirstName` or `firstname` inside your database, You can change it accordingly :)

Comment: Wow, than you very much :) Just one small problem, can I get this to work with my log in code? Or do I just add this above my log in code? Thanks again :)

Comment: You can just replace it with your existing login code :) You're welcome :)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not let me log in for some reason. I click log in, and it does not state whether or not I am logged in. Thanks :)

Comment: Here is the original code: https://eval.in/383172 and the new code: https://eval.in/383171 Thanks :)

Comment: Oh man.... There are few more bugs in the code.... You are missing the if_isset and few parts. Never worry, i will get you it :)

Comment: You shall try the latest eval and reply if any help needed

Comment: Thanks for this new code, but now it is stating: "Undefined index: FirstName" on line "echo 'Welcome Mr.<b>'.$row['FirstName'].'</b><br>'; //Just to show you output" and "$_SESSION["FirstName"]  = $row['FirstName'];" Thank you for all of your help :)

Comment: Do you have the coloumn `FirstName` in your users table ?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot to check it. It is working perfectly now. Just one more thing, can I get it to display the last name aswell? Thank you for all of your help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<?php   if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT firstname,lastname,Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?")){
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]);
$stmt->execute();
//$stmt->store_result();
//$checklog = $stmt->num_rows;
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $_SESSION['firstname'] = $results['firstname'];
 $_SESSION['lastname'] = $results['lastname'];

print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Hi I am getting the error: "Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given" on the line: "$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);", Sorry if I have got something wrong, I am quite new to PHP